# Markdown images using html img src

Tags: bug, markdown

The Markdown help text says that [it's possible to embed images](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images) using an HTML `<img src="...">` construct. The [definitive guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) (search for `img`) also seems imply that percentages are permitted.

This doesn't work for me.

Here is an embedded image:

↑ Or rather, it's not.

Here is the instruction: `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP6tZ.png" width="20%" height="20%">`

Comment: Why do you think the definitive guide seems to imply percentages are permitted? All it says is that the width and height can be up to 999, and that the mobile site has a max-width of 99%. Why do you need this, anyway?

Comment: @muru It's not definite, but the preceding paragraph states that, "_The following attributes are allowed on the <img> tag, but note that the mobile theme enforces a maximum width of **90%**..._". Why do  I want it? I have a high resolution screenshot from my mobile phone and I wanted to constrain the rendered view to 30% while leaving the image intact in case someone needed the detail.

Comment: i.e., there's a `max-width: 90%` in the mobile CSS. (typo in my first comment) I don't see how that translates to % being allowed  in these attributes. It even says hat the `px` isn't allowed, so I'd think they have a pretty strict filter there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a high resolution screenshot from my mobile phone and I wanted to constrain the rendered view to 30% while leaving the image intact in case someone needed the detail.

Then `height` and `width` are the wrong way to go about it, since the user still has to download the large image anyway. What you should use is imgur's built-in thumbnailing facilities. For a given image `https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP6tZ.png`, you can get thumbnails of various sizes by tacking on an `l`, `m`, or `s` before the extension:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP6tZl.png

  [image]
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP6tZm.png

  [image]
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP6tZs.png

  [image]

Then you can set a link on the image to the original:

```
[![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP6tZm.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP6tZ.png)
```

[image]

An example of this: [one of my Meta SE posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277913/270345)

A list of possible options, from [this blog post](https://thomas.vanhoutte.be/miniblog/imgur-thumbnail-trick/):

- s = Small Square (90×90)
- b = Big Square (160×160)
- t = Small Thumbnail (160×160)
- m = Medium Thumbnail (320×320)
- l = Large Thumbnail (640×640)
- h = Huge Thumbnail (1024×1024)

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you. I had no idea. When you write, "_What you should use is imgur's built-in thumbnailing facilities_", how was I supposed to know even to look for this feature? There's nothing in the obviously available help text, nothing on the "Insert an image by drag'n'drop « here »" overlay. Does this then generate a new question as an enhancement request to provide information about Imgur's thumbnailing features?

Comment: @roaima adding that to the docs somewhere would be a worthy feature request.

Comment: Thank you. https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4670/100397