# Knowing about Imgur's thumbnailing abilities

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, help-center

In [this answer to another meta question](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4669/100397) I have been told about the [thumbnailing features](https://thomas.vanhoutte.be/miniblog/imgur-thumbnail-trick/) available within Imgur. I for one had no idea that these features were even available, and hadn't even considered to look for them.

Since Imgur is the default route for enabling users to upload images to questions and answers, could we please have an explanation section linked from either the [Meta help text for images](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images) or even from the Drag'n'Drop popup that appears when someone clicks on the « [insert image » edit button.